# Eclipse Compare View keeps refreshing the window after every typed character :@

Tags: java, eclipse

There is a terribly annoying thing in Eclipse that I can't find a way to disable.
Every time I compare 2 files/folders and type in one of the two opened files, it keeps refreshing all the time!
This is awfully frustrating because if the file is large enough whenever it refreshes it always jumps to the top of the document and back to the cursor and sometimes even gets stuck at the top.

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable or at least delay this refreshing by a couple of seconds? It can really mess with nerves if this happens every second.

Answer (score 0):

It will automatically update any open editor that's associated with the files being edited in order to keep them in sync, just as it would if you had two editors associated with a file. For a small file, this seems to work fine. If you have odd behavior for larger files, then you should file a bug with Eclipse and provide an example of the file and exactly what you do to make this happen.

I don't think there is any preference to add a delay in updating the other editor.

Comment: I believe I am. Help->About=Eclipse IDE for Java Developers/

Version: Indigo Service Release 1/
Build id: 20110916-0149. But the fact is that I've observed this problem a long time ago too, it's just that I hadn't used it for quite some time so I forgot all about it. Could this maybe be some kind of annoying feature?

Comment: Well it's a good feature but just behaves in an annoying way sometimes it seems. See my revised answer.

Comment: "provide an example of the file and exactly what you do to make this happen" - any larger file will do and all it takes is typing a single character anywhere and waiting for a second. Guess I'll have to report this too.

Comment: You should say what you mean by larger file though, 3K, 40K, 400K?

Comment: It is simply not noticeable with smaller files and is affected by your PCs' performance, but the size does not matter, it's always there.